iOS async completion block not called
I have a very weird situation in GCD in my code, and here's a minimum reproducible code:

- (void)runMyCode {
  __block BOOL completed = NO;
  [self runSomeAsyncAPI:^{
    completed = YES;
  }];
  
  while (!completed) {
    [NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];
  }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self runMyCode];
  });
}

The completion block is not called at all. But if I don't dispatch_async, it works. This is strange.

I suspect that by invoking the run loop directly, you are messing up its queue and it loses the dispatch_after. In practice you would never invoke the run loop directly

Also note that when i use dispatch_async, the UI scrolling etc is completely fine (not blocked).

For context for future readers, here is a related prior question.

The problem is that it is dispatching runMyCode to a serial queue, spinning until complete is set. Thus, nothing else dispatched to that same serial queue can run until the code dispatched via dispatch_async finishes. Sure, the run loop can process events, but that serial queue is tied up. The dispatch_after (which will set complete) is unable to run on that same serial queue.
There are a number of ways of solving this:

The spinning on the run loop is a technique that predates GCD and is an anti-pattern, nowadays. The best solution would be to retire that and adopt asynchronous patterns. We can probably offer some reasonable, contemporary alternatives if we understood why you are spinning.

You can use different queues for the initial dispatch_async and the subsequent dispatch_after.

You can use a concurrent queue (either create your own or use a global queue).



Is viewDidLoad itself also called by a work item dispatched to the main queue?

Technically, this is an implementation detail to which we do not have access, but empirically we can clearly see that viewDidLoad obviously is not called by a dispatch work item. This is unsurprising given viewDidLoad predates GCD.

Hmmm, I thought main thread simply runs a for loop, which dequeues work items from the main queue and execute them. So my understanding was incorrect.

I can understand the confusion, but UI events are processed on the main thread’s “run loop”, an approach that, again, predates GCD. See the run loop discussion in the legacy Threading Programming Guide, which bears no reference to dispatch queues. The main run loop and GCD’s main queue are very different, but both happen to run on the main thread.

So I tried to follow your 3 suggestions above to resolve my problem, but I can't. Because my use case requires converting an async API into a synchronized one. The system API is called on main thread, and completed on main thread, so I have to use NSRunLoop. I wrote another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78533359/ios-scenecontinueuseractivity-deadlock-when-calling-a-synchronized-api. Thank you for your help!
